# Using the `once-only` macro

Tags: macros, common-lisp, practical-common-lisp

At the end of Ch 8 in [Practical Common Lisp](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/macros-defining-your-own.html), Peter Seibel presents the `once-only` macro. Its purpose is to mitigate a number of subtle  problems with variable evaluation in user-defined macros. Note I'm not trying to understand at this point how this macro works, as in some other posts, but just how to use it properly:

```
(defmacro once-only ((&rest names) &body body)
  (let ((gensyms (loop for n in names collect (gensym))))
    `(let (,@(loop for g in gensyms collect `(,g (gensym))))
      `(let (,,@(loop for g in gensyms for n in names collect ``(,,g ,,n)))
        ,(let (,@(loop for n in names for g in gensyms collect `(,n ,g)))
           ,@body)))))
```

The following is a sample (incorrect) contrived macro that attempts to exhibit several variable evaluation problems. It purports to iterate over a range of integers by some delta, returning the range:

```
(defmacro do-range ((var start stop delta) &body body)
  "Sample macro with faulty variable evaluations."
  `(do ((,var ,start (+ ,var ,delta))
        (limit ,stop))
       ((> ,var limit) (- ,stop ,start))
     ,@body))
```

For example, `(do-range (i 1 15 3) (format t "~A " i))` should print `1 4 7 10 13` and then return `14`.

The problems include 1) potential capture of the second occurrence of `limit`, since it occurs as a free variable, 2) potential capture of the initial occurrence of the bound variable `limit`, since it occurs in an expression along with other variables appearing in the macro parameters, 3) out of order evaluation, since `delta` will be evaluated before `stop`, even though `stop` appears before `delta` in the parameter list, and 4) multiple variable evaluations, since `stop` and `start` are evaluated more than once. As I understand it, `once-only` should fix these problems:

```
(defmacro do-range ((var start stop delta) &body body)
  (once-only (start stop delta limit)
    `(do ((,var ,start (+ ,var ,delta))
          (limit ,stop))
         ((> ,var limit) (- ,stop ,start))
       ,@body)))
```

However, `(macroexpand '(do-range (i 1 15 3) (format t "~A " i)))` complains about `limit` being an unbound variable. If I switch instead to `with-gensyms`, which should take care of problems 1 & 2 above only, the expansion proceeds without incident.

Is this an issue with the `once-only` macro? And does `once-only` really solve all the problems outlined above (and perhaps others)?

Comment: Why do you have `limit` at all? Couldn't you replace all uses with `,stop` in the `once-only` version?

Comment: @melpomene Yes, you're right. But I couldn't think of a better simple way to introduce the two basic kinds variable capture problems into the flawed macro (listed as problems 1 & 2 above). Any other ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The ONCE-ONLY macro**

To get rid of a warning that `N` is unused, I would change the macro to:

```
(defmacro once-only ((&rest names) &body body)
  (let ((gensyms (loop for nil in names collect (gensym))))
                           ; changed N to NIL, NIL is ignored
    `(let (,@(loop for g in gensyms collect `(,g (gensym))))
      `(let (,,@(loop for g in gensyms for n in names collect ``(,,g ,,n)))
        ,(let (,@(loop for n in names for g in gensyms collect `(,n ,g)))
           ,@body)))))
```

The purpose of this macro is to make sure that expressions are only evaluated once and in a defined order. For that it will introduce new uninterned variables and will bind the evaluation results to those. Inside he macro the new variables are available. The macro itself is provided to make writing macros easier.

**Using ONCE-ONLY in DO-RANGE**

Your example use of `ONCE-ONLY`:

```
(defmacro do-range ((var start stop delta) &body body)
  (once-only (start stop delta limit)
    `(do ((,var ,start (+ ,var ,delta))
          (limit ,stop))
         ((> ,var limit) (- ,stop ,start))
         ,@body)))
```

Why is there `LIMIT` in the `once-only` list? `limit` is undefined there. `LIMIT` is used inside the `ONCE-ONLY` form as a symbol, but outside there is no binding.

`ONCE-ONLY` expects that the list of names is a list of symbols and that these names are bound to forms. In your case `limit` is a symbol, but it is undefined.

We need to remove `limit` from the list of names:

```
(defmacro do-range ((var start stop delta) &body body)
  (once-only (start stop delta)
    `(do ((,var ,start (+ ,var ,delta))
          (limit ,stop))
         ((> ,var limit) (- ,stop ,start))
         ,@body)))
```

Now, what to do about `LIMIT`? Given that `once-only` provides bindings for the names, including for `STOP`, we can eliminate the symbol `LIMIT` and replace its use with `,stop`:

```
(defmacro do-range ((var start stop delta) &body body)
  (once-only (start stop delta)
    `(do ((,var ,start (+ ,var ,delta)))
         ((> ,var ,stop) (- ,stop ,start))
       ,@body)))
```

Example:

```
CL-USER 137 > (pprint
               (macroexpand
                '(do-range (i 4 10 2)
                   (print i))))

(LET ((#1=#:G2170 4)
      (#3=#:G2171 10)
      (#2=#:G2172 2))
  (DO ((I #1# (+ I #2#)))
      ((> I #3#) (- #3# #1#))
   (PRINT I)))
```

Comment: Works perfectly, great! But just to clarify for my understanding, it's not required to eliminate `limit` from the `do`. Just remove it from the `once-only` variables, and the original faulty macro then works.

Comment: @davypough: but then LIMIT is visible in the body,  also possibly shadowing another LIMIT. That's something we usually want to avoid.